# How to count number commas present in a CSV file

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

i have one csv file (ABC.txt) which has data as below :

1234,"djjdjd",45566,84774,45666,"djdjd"

i want to count number of commas present in a row of this CSV file.

how can i get this .

Comment: can you use java?, in java with split by "," and with the length of the array where you save the data splitted.

Comment: if you can use java: `String[] parts = text.split(",");`
the number of commas will be `parts.lenght-1`

Comment: replace the `,` with `''` deduct that strings length from the length of the original string

Comment: @AlexK. please can you explain with an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

REGEXP_COUNT() can do this easily:

```
with tbl(data_string) as
(
select '1234,"djjdjd",45566,84774,45666,"djdjd"' from dual
)
select regexp_count(data_string, ',') from tbl;
```

Answer (score 3):

For a pure (oracle) sql solution, try

```
 SELECT NVL(LENGTH(REGEXP_REPLACE(csv_row, '[^,]', '')), 0) FROM csv_table
```

assuming that you have the data from your csv file stored in the database.

The query replaces all charcters but commas in the original string, so determining the length becomes equivalent to counting.

Note that you might want to treat commas inside csv fields differently.

***Alternative*** ( see Alex K.'s comment )

```
SELECT LENGTH(csv_row) - NVL(LENGTH(REPLACE(csv_row, ',', '')), 0) FROM csv_table
```